# How to do a limited query like MySQL (LIMIT 0, 10) on Dbase?

Tags: limit, dbase

It is possible?

I know you can limit your queries with

```
 SELECT TOP 10 name FROM customers ORDER BY name
```

but how can I get names from 50 to 100?

I need to make a pagination but I can't find a way to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more simple way:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE RECNO()>50 AND RECNO()<=100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two opposite sorted `SELECT TOP` queries.

see: http://thepcspy.com/read/paging_in_sql/

```
SELECT name FROM 
 (SELECT TOP 50 name FROM
  (SELECT TOP 100 name FROM customers ORDER BY name ASC) AS a
 ORDER BY name DESC
 ) AS b
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Here, 50 is page size and 100 - 50 (ie: 50) is start index.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg and evyrob